# How to handle datepicker control?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using jquery ui `datepicker` control on a textbox and at the same time I am using `onblur` event for validation. Now the problem is when click on textbox and calendar appears and when you select date in it validation is performed on textbox. I try to handle it, but still it is appearing for a second.

Here is code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#date").datepicker({
        onSelect: function () {
            $("#span1").css("display", "none")
        }
    });
});

function check() {
    if ($("#date").val() == "") $("#span1").css("display", "inline-block");
}
```

For better understanding here is [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/4Vp9D/)

EDIT: final resolution: accepted closest answer first presented.

```
$("#date").datepicker({
    onClose: function() {
        check();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of on blur for the input box, you can also call check when the datepicker closes.

```
$("#date").datepicker({
    onSelect: function () {
        $("#span1").css("display", "none")
    },
    onClose: function() {
        check();
    }
});
```

Comment: did you remove the onblur from the inputbox?
works okay for me  http://jsfiddle.net/4Vp9D/24/   chrome and ie9

Comment: @user1390378 - people review edits from users with low level reputation.  Two people rejected this edit - I would have, based on your being the OP accepted this edit - however what you SHOULD do IF this resolves your issue is add a comment to this answer, accept this answer and place the edited code with and edit comment in your question.

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss: Thanks for explanation. Can you tell me why these two people rejected this? As my edit was just to improve answer.

Comment: Likely they did not see YOU were the one editing it and ALSO the OP - which was the only reason I clicked the "approve" button as your question does not clearly absolve the responsibility to keep your old functionality intact. - don't worry too much about it, just do as I suggested, posting the re-factored code in your question noting that it worked.

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss: Sorry my English is not good that's why I am  confused, you accepted my edit or rejected? because answer still showing old code.

Comment: I accepted it, but two others rejected it...so the majority rules...how it works for people who can review stuff - not all reviews are "perfect".

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss:Ok now I understand. Thanks for bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#date").datepicker({
        onSelect: function () {
            $("#span1").css("display", "none")
        }
    });
});


function check() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        if ($("#date").val() == "") 
            $("#span1").css("display", "inline-block")
            }, 100);
}
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/4Vp9D/26/

Comment: Sorry dear same problem again.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than invent your own wheel, may I suggest using this lightweight plugin?
http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

It plays nicely with jQuery UI DatePicker too and will save you from having to do your own validation on the date format.